# Service workers - termination prevented by DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

In developing a service worker, I want to test what happens when the service worker has been terminated (and later accessed). However, if I open DevTools to examine things, I see:

> Service Worker termination by a timeout timer was canceled because DevTools is attached.

Is there any way to set the DevTools to NOT prevent the 'normal' termination from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, but you can manually terminate a service worker in the **Application** panel by clicking **Stop**.

[image: The Service Worker pane]

Comment: Very true... I do it often enough!  This will have to do.